# Show a loading message while uploading to Imgur

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, imgur, connect-flash

I'm using `npm imgur` to have my users upload an image. Is there a way to have an uploading message pop up while I'm waiting for the the image to upload? I don't think I want the whole page to be reloaded, just a pop up of sorts.

This is what the basic code looks like in my `POST` method:

```
imgur
  .uploadFile(`myFile.jpeg`)
  .then((json) => {
    console.log(json);
   }
```

Is there a callback for `imgur.uploadFile` or is there something I can do right above this code maybe with flash and/or ejs?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just doing it in the ejs file with an `onclick` event on the `submit` button that creates an image tag linked to a loading-spin animation.